# My tricycle wont pedal and the chains are on it just wont engage

Tags: pedals, tricycle

While pedalng,I heard something snap on my tricycle and when I went to continue pedaling the pedals just spun,so I checked the chains and they were in place but wouldn't engage and turn the pedals and wheels.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. It sounds like something in the rear hub would be the likely suspect based on what you stated in your question. Pictures or even better a short video of what you are seeing would be EXTREMELY valuable to us to answer your question.  You can attach it by EDITING your question and adding it in there.

Comment: Does your cycle have a differential or a freewheel?  Photos would help.

Comment: I was told Its a differential because its a trike, but I don't know